# How do I target the last link in a list?

Tags: css, css-selectors

```
<li>
  <a href="site.com">Hello</a>
  <a href="site2.com">Bye</a>
  <small>July 7, 2011, 07:39</small>
</li>
```

How do I target that second link (i.e. the last link) in the list?

I tried `li a:last-child {  }` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`a:last-of-type` should work well for you there :D

Answer (score 0):

This seems working for your given html:

```
    $(function () {
        var txt = $("li a:last").text();
        var url = $("li a:last").attr('href');
        alert('txt=' + txt);
        alert('url=' + url);//alerts site2.com
    });
```

I tested in FF5. Please try it and let me know if it works.